# Automatically Enter Text from File into Text Field

Tags: html, forms, input, applescript, text-files

I have a `todo-sample.txt` that contains these 50 lines

**todo-sample.txt**

```
Optimize website images
Add pagination to blog post pages
Implement a responsive design for the website
Improve website load speed
Update website copy for SEO 
...
```

I'm trying to write a Apple script to parse those lines, each line I parse, then press enter.

Why press enter ? I want to use that script to faster test my input type text.

[image]

```
-- Set the path to the input file
set input_file to "/Users/bheng/Sites/notes/Todo/todo-sample.txt"

-- Open the input file
set file_handle to open for access input_file

-- Display a countdown timer
repeat with i from 3 to 1 by -1
    say i
    delay 1
end repeat
say "Go!"

-- Set the delay time between each line
set delay_time to 1

-- Read each line from the file and paste it into the current application
repeat with this_line in (read file_handle using delimiter return)
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke this_line
        delay delay_time
        key code 36 -- Press enter key
        delay delay_time
    end tell
end repeat

-- Close the input file
close access file_handle
```

## Result

My script parses the whole thing and enters the whole thing!

[image]

I'm open to any technology or other scripting language as well. I was thinking only AppleScript could do that! Please correct me if I am wrong.

Any guidance for me?

Answer (score 0):

Note the addition of the line repeat with this_line in paragraphs of (read file_handle) which splits the file contents into individual lines based on the newline character.

```
-- Set the path to the input file
set input_file to "/Users/bheng/Sites/notes/Todo/todo-sample.txt"

-- Open the input file
set file_handle to open for access input_file

-- Display a countdown timer
repeat with i from 3 to 1 by -1
    say i
    delay 1
end repeat
say "Go!"

-- Set the delay time between each line
set delay_time to 1

-- Read each line from the file and paste it into the current application
repeat with this_line in paragraphs of (read file_handle)
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke this_line
        key code 36 -- Press enter key
    end tell
end repeat

-- Close the input file
close access file_handle
```

## Result ✨

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**(read file_handle using delimiter return)** remains whole text (not the list) if the line breaks in the text file are **Linefeed** or some other instead of **Return**. To avoid guessing which line break is being used in the text file, it's better to use **paragraphs**.

Also, to read contents of the file, you don't need open it for access. Simply convert its Posix path to HFS path, to read then the whole contents using syntax **read HFSpath**:

```
-- Set the path to the input file
set input_file to "/Users/bheng/Sites/notes/Todo/todo-sample.txt"
set file_handle to input_file as text --> convereted to HFS path

-- Display a countdown timer
repeat with i from 3 to 1 by -1
    say i
    delay 1
end repeat
say "Go!"

-- Set the delay time between each line
set delay_time to 1

-- Read each line from the file and paste it into the current application
repeat with this_line in paragraphs of (read file_handle)
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke (this_line & return)
    delay delay_time
end repeat
```